# If $a>0$, $b>0$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, show that $a<b$ if and only if $a^n<b^n$.

Tags: real-analysis

If $a>0$, $b>0$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, show that $a<b$ if and only if $a^n<b^n$.  Hint: Use mathematical induction.
Having trouble with the proof that if $a<b$ then $a^n<b^n$.
So far I have;

Assume $a<b$
then $a^k<b^k$ for $k=1$

Assume $\exists m \in \mathbb{n}$ such that $a^m<b^m$

Then let $k=m+1$ so $a^{m+1}<b^{m+1}$

Then $a*a^m<b*b^m$

I'm not positive I can make the second assumption and if I can I don't know how to prove the last statement which would allow the extension into all natural numbers.

Comment: Assuming $a^m < b^m$, $a\ast a^m < b\ast a^m < b\ast b^m$. Hence $a^{m+1} < b^{m+1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Do it in two steps, $a^{m+1}=a^m a\lt a^m b\lt b^mb=b^{m+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

It's clear for $k=1$. Suppose it is true for $k=n$ then

$a^{n+1}=a\cdot a^{n}<a\cdot b^{n}<b\cdot b^{n}=b^{n+1}$.

Note that we used that $a>0$ and $b>0$ to preserve direction of inequality. That is we first used the induction hypothesis $a^{n}<b^{n}$ and then since $a>0$ we have:

$a^{n+1}=a\cdot a^{n}<a\cdot b^{n}$.

Then using that $a<b$ and that $b^{n}>0$ since $b>0$ we get:

$a\cdot b^{b}<b\cdot b^{n}=b^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way round,

Since $b^n - a^n = (b-a)[a^{n - 1} + a^{n - 2}b + ... + b^{n - 1}]$ $\cdots(1)$

Given $(1)$ is $> 0$ also for $a>0$ and $b>0$

$[a^{n - 1} + a^{n - 2}b + ... + b^{n - 1}]>0$

hence $b>a$.